# Partially fill a FLOT pie chart slice with color, starting at center

Tags: javascript, flot

Anyone know if this is possible?

Basically I need to be able to only partially shade a pie slice with color, say range of 0-10, where 0 means no color in pie slice, 10 means fully shaded. Thanks for any help!

Comment: An interesting problem. I wanted to try out some things to achieve your desired layout and came up with two different solutions, see the answers below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Disclaimer*: My other answer is rather hacky in regard to the legend and correct positioning of the pie charts but can work when you cannot modify the plugin code, so here a cleaner second version.)

This is not possible with default methods but relativly simple by directly changing the pie plugin. Copy the plugin ([source](http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/jquery.flot.pie.js), version 1.1) and make following changes to your local copy:

1. Line 395 and 406 in `function drawPie()`:
   Add `slices[i].radius` to the parameters for both `drawSlice()` calls.
2. Line 423 in `function drawSlice()`:
   Change the header of the function to

   ```
   function drawSlice(angle, color, fill, sliceRadius) {
   ```
3. Line 428 in `function drawSlice()`:
   Add this code:

   ```
   if (!jQuery.isNumeric(sliceRadius)) {
       sliceRadius = radius;                    
   }
   else if (sliceRadius >= 0.0 && sliceRadius <= 1.0) {
       sliceRadius = radius * sliceRadius;                    
   }
   ```
4. Line 441 to 443 (before inserting code from 3.) in `function drawSlice()`:
   Replace `radius` with `sliceRadius`.

After the above changes you can define a `radius` property for each datapoint / slice in the pie chart. This follows the same rules as the general `radius` property (if `radius` is between 0 and 1 it will be used as percentage of the general radius, otherwise it will be used as pixel value).

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jjrwh65k/) showing it with different values for the `radius` property:

```
var data = [{
    label: 'red',
    color: 'red',
    data: 1,
    radius: 100 // radius in pixel (about 50% here)
}, {
    label: 'green',
    color: 'green',
    data: 3
    // default is the general radius
}, {
    label: 'blue',
    color: 'blue',
    data: 2,
    radius: 0.8 // radius 80% of general radius (about 160 pixel here)
}];
```

Comment: Thanks so much Raidri! Your changes work perfectly for what I need. Have a good evening! Do I do anything else to give you points?

Comment: You can mark one answer (the one you think is better) as accepted by clicking the checkmark on the left under the votes. [FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) (Additionally you could upvote one or both answer(s), but you need 15 reputation to upvote. [Upvote privilege](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) )

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with default methods, but you can achieve something similar with some creativity:

1. Create one dataset for each range value, where each slice with this range value gets its normal color, all other slices get `color: 'transparent'`.
2. Draw a seperate pie chart for each range value, with the options set to something like this:

   ```
       pie: {
           show: true,
           radius: 0.7 // example for a range value of 7
       }
   ```
3. Position all pie charts on top of each other by using css.

Result (for two different range values: 7 and 10):
[image]

You may want to do a manual legend since only the topmost legend is fully visible. Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o84jr9fh/) with a working example from which you can start to develop your own code.